# Discord.js Bot global Usernumber

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

So I'm very new to node.js/discord.js, thats why I want to ask you something. On my first Bot I want to mak a global User Count, witch shout look [like in the Picture below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb4rm.jpg). I tried the following code, but with this, the usercount is changing evry second.

```
    client.on('message', message => {

  if (message.content === 'm!info') {

        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()

    .setColor('#0099ff')

    .setTitle('Informations')

    .addField('Version','V 0.3')

    .addField('Dev.','@myname')

    .addField('Ping', `Der Bot hat einen Ping von **${client.ping} ms**!`)

    .addField('Server', `${client.guilds.size}`)

    .addField('User', `${client.users.size} (Verbugt)`)

    .setTimestamp()



    message.channel.send(embed);

  }



});
```

Would be great If someone can help me. [Thats the unrealistic Usernumber](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIyZa.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client.users` are the cached users. You can do it this way:

```js
let userCount = client.guilds.map((g) => g.memberCount).reduce((p, c) => p + c);
console.log(userCount); // 3241 for example.
```

The userCount won't change until a member joins or left a server. The disadvantage is that if a member is present on several servers, he will be counted twice. Otherwise, you are obliged to use `client.users.size`...